# (Arduino) I want to create an array of uint8_t array

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I want to store hard-coded a relation of HEX characters in uint8_t as an array, in php for example a would do something like

```
$relation = [
    'uint8here-justasample',
    'uint8here-justasample',
    'uint8here-justasample',
    'uint8here-justasample',
    'uint8here-justasample'
];
```

How to do this in Arduino?

This is the uint8_t array that will be stored in the array of uint8

```
uint8_t event[8] = {'0','0','0','0','7','0','1','5'};
```

Comment: You want a way to store hex specified values in an array?  {0x01, 0x02, ..., 0xFF}. Single quotes are for characters, not integer literals.

Comment: Yes,, that what I want, not sure what to do, I'm from the php world. @MitchellKline At the end I want a uint8 to generate a CRC

Comment: E.g. uint8_t event[3] = {0, 0x07, 0xA5}. Note that uint8_t isn't guaranteed to be defined by the implementation, but it's probably fine to use on arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is:

```
uint8_t const event[][8] = 
{  {'0','0','0','0','7','0','1','5'}
,  {'0','0','0','0','7','0','1','5'}
,  {'0','0','0','0','7','0','1','5'}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The values in that "event[8]" array are the same in decimal.

```
unsigned char event[8] = {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 5};
```

is equivalent to uint8_t. You can print this array using:

```
for(int i; i<=sizeof(event); i++){
   Serial.print("0x");
   Serial.println(event[i], HEX);
}
```

Your arduino serial monitor will be:
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7 0x0 0x1 0x5